# Connect iPhone app with iPad app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, networking

I am trying to create an app that will run on an iPhone and an iPad. The idea is the when the app is launched on the iPad it will act as a spectator to whatever is happening on the iPhone (with the same app running).

For example: If this was a drawing app whatever is drawn on the iPhone will appear in realtime on the iPad screen.

I am struggling to identify the correct mechanism for doing this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: To detect the other app you can use Bonjour.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing

Comment: Thank you I will do some reading on this.

Comment: @isoyaboy check out Multipeer Connectivity Framework for iOS. It hides all the complexity of configuring bonjour and provides a decent api to connect 2 or more apps installed on devices as peers and share data between them. Reference link https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/index.html Tutorial Link http://nshipster.com/multipeer-connectivity/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are targeting ios 7 and above `Multipeer Connectivity Framework` is the way to implement this. It provides u with a decent api to connect multiple apps on devices which become peers and then can share data with each other.

Check out [Multipeer Connectivity Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/index.html)

Here's a good tutorial teaching how to implement it.
[Tutorial](http://nshipster.com/multipeer-connectivity/)

Multipeer Framework connects peers(apps installed on multiple devices in your case) on local Wifi Network or by using Bluetooth.
If you want to `share data over the internet between your apps installed on multiple devices` in my opinion `HTML5 WebSockets` is the way to go.

Here's a nice third party library to implement it in iOS.
[Socket Rocket Websockets iOS Library](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket)

Comment: Thanks Nogfel, I think I will go down this route.